# scopes Fastapi OAUTH2

Tags: oauth-2.0, fastapi

So i have to do scopes for auth and how i need to check if user had this scope
and how i can connect other func for scope
[image]

I just have to write scopes for routes or for each request

And can i do route for special scope in the frontend ?

Comment: my question is how to add scope to ApiRouter ???